# Excel 2016/ Help to create a function to add number(48.20) as hours.minutes to a Date(2018-03-04 08:00)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I would increase the Date(2018-03-04 08:00) by given number.

Ex.

Cell A1 (2018-03-04 08:00)

Cell A2 (48.20)   ///Number as hour and minutes which in this case its 2days and 20 minutes

cell A3 (adding the numbers A2 on the Date A1) = (2018-03-06 08:20)

Comment: Why isn't A2 formatted as a time? The value decimal in `48.20` means **two-tenths of an hour**, not 20 minutes --  So that's actually 12 minutes. If it was formatted as a time, ie: `48:20` then that would make it much easier

Comment: What K.Davis said.  But if you are receiving the data in that form and can't control how it's entered, is it formatted as text or as a number set to display two decimal places?  How do single digit portions appear (e.g., does 8 hrs appear as 08 or 8, does 2 mins appear as .2 or .02)?  Can you change how A2 is stored (makes a huge difference in the solution)?

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming**

- A2 contents is a decimal number representing hours and minutes, and it is in the 00.00 format (so that 48 hrs, 2 minutes would be 48.02), then:

---

```
=A1+TEXT(A2*100,"00\:00")
```

If you prefer more obscure formulas, try:

```
=A1+DOLLARDE(A2,60)/24
```

Answer (score -2):

The main difficulty in this question is that the value to be added is recorded as the decimal number **48.20**, but it is to be interpreted as **48 hours and 20 minutes**.  This is presumably a requirement.  This answer assumes that the minutes are coded as two digit numbers, so 2 minutes would be .02 rather than .2.

This solution converts the decimal number to days and minutes, and then adds those numbers to the date.  The integer portion of the number represents the hours, which can be converted to whole days with either of these formulas in C2:

`C2=INT(B2/24)`or

`C2=INT(CONVERT(B2,"hr", "day"))`

**Note that this works only for cases where the hours are a multiple of whole days.  It won't yield a correct answer if the hours are not whole days.**  Also, the second formula won't work if the entries are actually stored as text.

Next, the fractional portion is converted into minutes in cell D2:

`=100*(B2-TRUNC(B2))` or

`=(B2-INT(B2))*100` or

`=MOD(B2,1)*100`

Last, these intermediate results are added to the date using this final formula in E2:

`=DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),DAY(A2)+C2)+TIME(HOUR(A2),MINUTE(A2)+D2,SECOND(A2))`

[image]

*Note: ignore the typo in this image.  The third column should be labeled "Days" rather than "Hours".*

Here, Day(A2)+C2 adds 2 days and Minutes(A2)+D2 adds 20 minutes.

The final result in Cell E2 is 2018-03-06 08:20.

**Note:**

- A2 & E2 are formatted as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM.
- B2 is formatted as Number.
- C2 & D2 are formatted as General.

This solution uses helper columns to assist with the explanation.  The helper columns can be incorporated into a single formula by substituting the helper cell formula for the cell reference.

Comment: This doesn't reflect the question.  The question states that what is in the "add" cell is the number 48.20, and that is the crux of the question.  This answer bears no relationship to the question.  Please don't post random answers.

Comment: @fixer1234, OP said, "cell A3 (adding the numbers A2 on the Date A1) = (2018-03-06 08:20)" and exactly what I've suggested the OP. Where A2 has 48:20 and A1 has 2018-03-04 08:00. OP's data are in Column mine in Row, this is  the only difference.

Comment: Reread the question.  A2 contains the decimal number 48.20, not a time.  The question asks how to translate that value into a time where the 48 portion means 48 hours and the .20 portion means 20 minutes so that it can be added to the time in A1.  The comments and Ron Rosenfeld's answer also make this clear.

Comment: @fixer1234,, "Cell A2 (48.20) ///Number as hour and minutes which in this case its 2days and 20 minutes" . that's Y I've suggested the Format HH:MM for A2 to get the correct result. And read K. Davis has also suggested "Why isn't A2 formatted as a time? "

Comment: K. Davis already suggested that the OP change it to a useful format.  But it currently is not in that format.  The question is how to solve the problem given the OP's current starting point.  A solution based on a different starting point is not an answer to this question.  If it was already in the form of a time, the question would not even be necessary.

Comment: @fixer1234,, just check I've edited the answer and used 48.20 to calculate the New Date. Hope you like it and mark it as the Answer :-)

Comment: Where does D2 come from?  How do you know exactly how the add cell is displayed (e.g., what if .2 = 2 minutes and .20 = 20 minutes); the question isn't clear, and you don't state any assumptions.  That's a problem with answering unclear questions.  Also col C isn't hours.

Comment: This is a bad, nebulous question that you seem intent on trying to answer. The answer got off to a very bad start, and you keep trying to patch it. It's turned into a monster. There's no way "this will help the OP and many, many others too", no matter how much you hope. Please just put it out of its misery. If you are still obsessed with answering this question, just start over fresh and create from scratch a well thought-out answer. BTW, adding trite noise--variations of "I do hope this will help you"--to every bad answer doesn't make them good answers, it just makes people's eyeballs itch.

Comment: @fixer1234, now read the final version it meets every aspect of the OP's query. Now D2 has also formula to convert the fractional part into minutes. First one discovered by Bandersnatch other two included by me to justify my efforts. Bottom line of Method 1 is, "Cell C2 must be in [H]:mm Format". Because technically it's wrong practice to add Number with Time and I do feel we must point out such mistakes while answering. At many junctures I've observed such technical mistake so that I always tried  to assume the correct version and created answers, during this some of my assumptions failed,.

Comment: ,, I never bothered about any thing except, how could I support the OP. And the worst part is that during all such I hardly found OP in the discussion !! Any way it's over :-). Get ready for the next,, :-)

Comment: @RajeshS, I did read the "final" version, which was what prompted me to leave the comment.  Answers aren't a historical record of their development.  When somebody finds it a year from now, none of the process information will matter.  They'll find the question and your answer.  The answer should just answer what was asked as directly as possible.  If you want to add extraneous commentary about how the OP could improve their process, do it in comments.  For all we know, the OP gets handed the data and has no control over it.  Doing their process differently isn't part of the question.

Comment: @Bandersnatch, thanks for Edit 2. I've included two more formula to convert the decimal part into minutes along with few edits to give final shape to the answer. :-)